# MySQL Categories Table Structure

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need to design a db for a website which has different sections, for example: products, articles & members.

Each one of these departments should be separated into different categories, for example:

#### Products categories:

1. Shoes
2. Shirts
3. Hats

#### Members categories:

1. VIP Members
2. Regular Members
3. Discount Members

and so on..

My question is: should I use one big categories table which has a flag in each row that indicates which kind of category is it (such as `members_category`,`products_category`) or should I use a separate category table for each department?

Comment: Your product categories seem to differ from Member Categories. But then it also makes sense to have a category table with a category id, name and then that ID becomes a fk to memeber, article and product...

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, you should use separate category tables. That will make it easy to declaratively enforce referential integrity, without worrying about connecting to a wrong kind of category.

For example, you can simply create a FOREIGN KEY between PRODUCT and PRODUCT_CATEGORY tables and a FOREIGN KEY between MEMBER and MEMBER_CATEGORY, and the database will automatically "defend" itself if you try to connect a product to a member category or a member to a product category.

Answer (score 0):

to create table for all category type is not good idea.
if you want to use one categories table you have to Create one more table for category types.

expample ->

CategoryType table -> ID,Name

1. Products Categories
2. Members Categories

Category table -> Name,CategoryTypeID

insert a category;

> 'Shoes',1(Products CategoryTypeID)
>
> 'VIP members',2(Members CategoryTypeID)

hopefully helps it

Answer (score 0):

i think its good idea to use different table for different category. use references(foreign key) to map between them.
by this your debugging will easy on database.

if you manage all category in same table then management of table is hard.